# Необходимы ли запятые в предложении?

Tags: запятые

Необходимы ли запятые в данном предложении: "Сможете зарабатывать на своём хобби(,) после первого месяца обучения(,) и будете иметь постоянный финансовый поток"?

Я смотрела в интернете правила, но не нашла ничего того, чтобы подходило. Хотелось бы узнать, не пропустила ли я чего-то. Пожалуйста, подскажите, необходимы ли запятые, если да, то не могли бы вы сослаться на правило?

Answer (score 1):

Первая запятая не нужна, потому что в вашем предложении слово «после» принадлежит к служебной части речи и является производным предлогом. Предлог не обособляется.

Вторая запятая тоже не нужна, так как в предложении присутствуют однородные члены предложения, которые связаны союзом «и».

---

Я бы на вашем месте изменил предложение:

1. После первого месяца обучения вы сможете зарабатывать на своём хобби и будете иметь постоянный финансовый поток.
2. Уже после первого месяца обучения вы овладеете навыками, которые позволят вам зарабатывать на своём хобби. Вы на своём примере узнаете, что значит фраза «постоянный финансовый поток».
3. Самый важный ресурс — это ваше время. Потратив ровно один месяц на обучение, вы начнёте зарабатывать на своём хобби и будете иметь постоянный финансовый поток.

Ну или что-то в этом роде.